# Is there a GaussView 5 Alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation

I have Gaussian (G09) for Linux, but not gaussview5. What are some alternatives to guassview, to view Gaussian output files?

Answer (score 0):

There are many programs that analyze the output file of Gaussian (MacMolPlt, Gabedit, Avogadro). Among them, Molden is the very best alternative that I know:
                         http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/
Because it is easy to use and includes many features such as: visualization of molecular vibrations, isosurfaces or contour plots of molecular orbitals, electron densities, diference of densities; also, allows the calculation of electrostatic potential, the electron Localization Function (ELF), generate the wfn file (input file for made QTAIM calculations with programs like AIMALL, MULTIWFN), perform molecular mechanics calculations, etc.